# Running Script on Startup

Tags: java, linux

Essentially what I'd like to achieve is add a .jar file to the startup of my Linux computer. I created a script that would run the file and then tried adding that script to run when the system boots up.

I have a .java file on my desktop named **Box.java**. The file contains no errors and I manually compiled it and it was working fine. I then created a script on my desktop called **start.sh** and it's contents are

```
#!/bin/bash

javac /home/maple/Desktop/Box.java
```

So what this should do is compile the java class and the result would be a class file on my desktop called **Box.class**

I then created a file in **/etc/init.d/** and it is called **start_java* it's contents are

```
#!/bin/sh

home/maple/Desktop/start.sh
```

I then opened up terminal and did

```
chmod +x /etc/init.d/start_java
```

I know the sh file will compile a java file and not run a file, in the completed copy I will be doing it with a jar file. How can I add that jar to startup without using a 3rd party software or any pre-installed programs?

**EDIT:** The current way I have it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You just want to do the same thing you already did, but changing the content of **start.sh** to:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar <filename>
```

Comment: Guess I wasn't clear enough. The script is not working. The .class file is not made.

Comment: I didn't want to go deeper on that,  but I guess your startup.sh is executed; but it is executed by `root` user, so the compiled file won't be stored in `/home/maple/Desktop`. You could try editing it to `javac -d /home/maple/Desktop /home/maple/Desktop/Box.java`